# Imported jar in gradle, compiles, but not recognized by Android Studio (0.2.10)

Tags: android-studio

This is an annoying one. 
I have a simple project structure which is based on Gradle, very similar to other projects I have. 
The project has these imports:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.+'
    compile files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-core-2.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/jackson-databind-2.1.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/zip4j_1.3.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.1.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.1.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/httpmime-4.1.3.jar')
    compile project(":grid_lib")
}
```

Which works well.

The only problem is that the Android Studio does not recognize those classes, so they are all in red and have no intel.
**Very annoying!**

I've been banging my head against the wall for too long, so I'm trying here now. What do you say guys? Any ideas?

Thanks :-)

**Edit**

I've answered my own questions, for those who find the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

well, to answer my own question...

Sometimes Android Studio's Gradle goes haywire, and I found a simple fix:

1. Restart Android Studio
2. Create a new project (doesn't matter where or name)
3. Wait for it finish downloading its gradle stuff
4. Restart android studio

For other gradle problems, an additional step may be required, which is copying the gradle wrapper (gradlew files, and gradle folder, *not* the .gradle folder) from the newly created project to your own project, and re-import your project.

You can now delete the new project... of course.

### Edit:

Gradle's version keep changing.
If you are still having trouble, try this-

1. Edit your gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties file, and update the distribution url's version. Currently it should be 1.8, but it may change in the future. So you can use a "new project" to find out what the version should be. Example: distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.8-bin.zip
2. Edit your build.gradle file, and change the minimum version to 0.6.+ - and again it may change in the future. Example for current versions: classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
3. Restart your Android Studio and recompile.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you just create an empty new project or copy the jackson gradle settings over?

Comment: Just created a new project, it made Android Studio re-download the correct updated version of Gradle, which it did not know it was missing.

Comment: Ah no, doesnt seem to work. Which version of gradle are you using?

Comment: Restarting Android Studio really shouldn't be necessary. Clicking on the "Sync Project with Gradle Files" button in the toolbar should be sufficient.

Comment: yeah but that proved to not be helpful at all... restarting was required in several cases. and also very recently when the minimum version bar was raised.

Comment: hmm those have been my settings all along! doesnt make a difference

Comment: to clarify "so they are all in red and have no intel." what exactly was red? For me the project builds fine, except the jackson annotations are in red. Android doesnt seem to recognize the jackson imports in the file. But when it builds its all okay.. kinda weird

Comment: Hmm, try to clean the project from .gradle folder, idea etc. and then import it from to Android Studio from Gradle.

Comment: I'm having this issue currently, and nothing here has worked.. Any other pointers?

Comment: Android Studio 1.0 brought many updates to Gradle, and you probably have to update gradle version in build.gradle to 1.0, and let Android Studio upgrade Gradle Wrapper automatically.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem once I tried to upgrade Crashlytics to Fabric which cost me few hours to solve it.
I tried cleaning the project and rebuilding it from IDE and Terminal, closed Android Studio and opened it again, synced the gradle, checked out to other git branches and so on. Non of them solved the problem! 
As a final attempt I closed the project and imported it to Android Studio again and the error was gone!!! I couldn't find any explanation for why it happened but it could be some sort of caching issue on the gradle which was not being cleared in normal ways.

Comment: Crashalytics and Fabric are a complete waste of time. AND you have crash analytics in Google Play, and they're great.

Comment: Not really!!! I found Crashlytics really helpful on my project and didn't really cause any issue. Found bugs and Crashes that have never been reported on Google Play analytics and also the fact that you can make custom logs that would be passed along with crash logs, might be really handy! However I admit that migration from Crashlytics to Fabric was a pain.

Comment: Yes I had to migrate a project to Fabric and gave up midway. It had so many conflicts with other standard libraries and it was not worth the time of trying to figure it out....

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the problem was that i was using an old version of a jar library, and when updating to a newer version Android Studio was not recognising the classes, but it was compiling anyway. But i got this annoying red font color and underlining.

None of the solutions in this thread worked for me.

The solution for me was adding in the build.gradle the following:

```
repositories {
    flatDir{
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

And of course, the common (but these lines come by default):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much I've been stuck for days haha!